# Get the names of all employees who never took a vacation day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table for Employee and DaysTaken

[image]

Hi, i m facing a problem that a employee'John Smith' take 'sick day' and 'vacation'. 
This is my current answer

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', MiddleName, ' ',  LastName) AS 'CompleteName' from Employee
RIGHT JOIN DaysTaken ON
Employee.EmployeeID =
DaysTaken.EmployeeID
WHERE (DaysTaken.vacationtype = 'sick day')
```

Comment: detail added. Seek for help, tq.

Comment: I would recommend to ask other question. Because this has been closed & take a time to re-open.

Answer (score 0):

Right outer joins are hard to read and it is not recommended using them. In your query you select all sick days and outer join the related employees. As probably all sick days taken are taken by an employee, this is the same as a mere inner join.

So, you select all employees' sick days. Then with `DISTINCT` you show each employee who has ever been sick. This is completely different from what your request title asks for. (And joining all these rows only to dimiss most of them with `DISTINCT` is not an approach I would follow anyway.)

Your request title says

> Get the names of all employees who never took a vacation day

In order to get the employee names, you would select from the employees table. You only want employees where a condition is met. A condition belongs best in the `WHERE` clause. The condition is that there doesn't exist a vaction entry for the employee. We check for existence of a row in a table with `[NOT] EXISTS` or `[NOT] IN`.

### With NOT EXISTS

```
select concat_ws(' ', firstname, middlename, lastname) as complete_name
from employee e
where not exists
(
  select null
  from daystaken dt
  where dt.vacationtype = 'vacation'
  and dt.employeeid = e.employeeid
);
```

### With NOT IN

```
select concat_ws(' ', firstname, middlename, lastname) as complete_name
from employee
where employeeid not in
(
  select employeeid
  from daystaken
  where vacationtype = 'vacation'
);
```

In the image there are only rows with `vacationtype` 'vacation' or 'sick day'. If there can beothers, `where vacationtype = 'vacation'` may still be appropriate, but you may just as well need another condition, e.g. `where vacationtype <> 'sick day'`.